# How to get the nearest area from a list of locations?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, geolocation, latitude-longitude

I have a API which returns a list of different areas within a city with the weather at that area. I want to get the nearest area based on my current location.

API returns

- Area
- Latitude
- Longitude
- Weather

How to find the nearest area based on this data?

Comment: Use Reverse Geocoding API to pass Latitude and Longitude and get the address. https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/#ReverseGeocoding

Comment: Thanks 0x8badf00d, My next step was to get the address based on the filtered coordinates. This API was helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You would have to create CLLocation objects for all the areas, plus one for the current location of the user. Then use a loop similar to the one below to get the closest location:

```
NSArray *allLocations; // this array contains all CLLocation objects for the locations from the API you use

CLLocation *currentUserLocation;

CLLocation *closestLocation;
CLLocationDistance closestLocationDistance = -1;

for (CLLocation *location in allLocations) {

    if (!closestLocation) {
        closestLocation = location;
        closestLocationDistance = [currentUserLocation distanceFromLocation:location];
        continue;
    }

    CLLocationDistance currentDistance = [currentUserLocation distanceFromLocation:location];

    if (currentDistance < closestLocationDistance) {
        closestLocation = location;
        closestLocationDistance = currentDistance;
    }
}
```

One thing to note is that this method of calculating a distance uses a direct line between point A and point B. No roads or other geographical objects are taken into account.

Comment: Thanks, Exactly what I want!!! Just a minor typo, can you change the closestDistance to closestLocationDistance?

Comment: Thnx Buddy you save my one day.. gr8 work.. please replace this line..  if (currentDistance < closestDistance) ... into if (currentDistance < closestLocationDistance).. :-)

Comment: @Scott How to get CLLocation objects. Actually I have an array of latitude and longitude. Do I convert all the objects into CLLocation objectus

Comment: @Sudha: Yes, you can simply create the objects by calling `[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latitude longitude:longitude]`. Note that your `latitude` and `longitude` variables need to be of type `CLLocationDegrees`, so you may have to do some casting/converting there.

Comment: Does this need internet connection ?